# What is the meaning of file-static out-of-line, global out-of-line and no out-of-line copy of function in inlining

Tags: c, gcc, inline, inline-functions, os161

I was reading the source code of OS/161 and encountered inline support code. I am not able to understand the comment provided. The comment is :-

```
/*                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 * Material for supporting inline functions.                                                                                                                                                                
 *                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 * A function marked inline can be handled by the compiler in three                                                                                                                                         
 * ways: in addition to possibly inlining into the code for other                                                                                                                                           
 * functions, the compiler can (1) generate a file-static out-of-line                                                                                                                                       
 * copy of the function, (2) generate a global out-of-line copy of the                                                                                                                                      
 * function, or (3) generate no out-of-line copy of the function.                                                                                                                                           
 *                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 * None of these alone is thoroughly satisfactory. Since an inline                                                                                                                                          
 * function may or may not be inlined at the compiler's discretion, if                                                                                                                                      
 * no out-of-line copy exists the build may fail at link time with                                                                                                                                          
 * undefined symbols. Meanwhile, if the compiler is told to generate a                                                                                                                                      
 * global out-of-line copy, it will generate one such copy for every                                                                                                                                        
 * source file where the inline definition is visible; since inline                                                                                                                                         
 * functions tend to appear in header files, this leads to multiply                                                                                                                                         
 * defined symbols and build failure. The file-static option isn't                                                                                                                                          
 * really an improvement, either: one tends to get compiler warnings                                                                                                                                        
 * about inline functions that haven't been used, which for any                                                                                                                                             
 * particular source file tends to be at least some of the ones that                                                                                                                                        
 * have been defined. Furthermore, this method leads to one                                                                                                                                                 
 * out-of-line copy of the inline function per source file that uses                                                                                                                                        
 * it, which not only wastes space but makes debugging painful.                                                                                                                                             
 */
```

Please can anyone explain me what do they mean by file-static out-of-line, global out-of-line and no out-of-line copy of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “normal” implementation of a function creates it as a subroutine in the assembly language or machine code generated by the compiler: It is a sequence of instructions that is called by other routines, and it returns when it is complete.

Since calling a function and returning from it may have some overhead, a compiler may instead generate an *inline* implementation of the function. For example, with this code:

```
int square(int x) { return x*x; }
...
void foo(...)
{
    ...
    y = square(x);
}
```

the compiler could choose to compile `foo` as if it were:

```
void foo(...)
{
    ...
    y = x*x;
}
```

Thus, the compiler embeds the contents of the function inside the routine that called it. This is called an inline implementation.

The comments you quote use *out-of-line* to refer to the normal implementation of a function as an actual subroutine. It is not a commonly used phrasing, but is not unusual either.